# Adding a new line in a TextBlock when needed

Tags: windows-phone-7, newline, textblock

I'm reading JSON from a WebService and put my data in a list of textblocks (wrapped in grids).
Sometimes the text is long and I would like that the textblock would add automatically a new line if needed (instead going to the right endlessly).

I've read somewhere that I should wrap the textblock in a Label (not recognized by VS2010?)..

I cannot put <\newline> or \n or anything because I don't know where or when.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the TextWrapping property to Wrap:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I already tried this but it didn't worked because I find out that my column had Width="auto"! :D

Answer (score 2):

Add like this in your xaml

```
 <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set TextWrapping property of Textblock to Wrap from Designer or from XAML....

Comment: Unless you expand this with some example code, ths should really be a comment.